# C# recursive programming: jump onto previous step in code

Tags: c#, recursion, methods, dynamic, sudoku

I have been given the task to write a sudoku program, which solves the sudoku wikipedia example.
The method which solves the sudoku puzzle has to be a recursive method.
It first checks if the sudoku board is valid (sudoku rules: no twice occuring numbers in same row, column and box), then gets the first empty field it can write in and writes the first value (number 1) in field. After that, the method calls itself again (recursion).

My method looks like this:

```
private bool SolveSudoku(int[,] board)
    {
        // if board not valid, return false
        if (!CheckBoardValid(board))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // if board full, return true
        var nextField = GetFirstEmpty(board);
        if (nextField is null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        for (int value = 1; value < 10; value++)
        {
            board[nextField.Value.X, nextField.Value.Y] = value;
            var solved = SolveSudoku(board);
            // if solved, do nothing
            // if not solved, undo this step and try writing next number (value++) in field
        }
        return false;
    }
```

How can I undo the last step, if it is not valid?

Comment: Remember the previous value and set it back?

Comment: I recommend checking out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_UYXzGuqvM

Comment: of the top of my head you'd want to record the current position before calling the board[nextfield.value.x,...]
and then reverting to this position, then incrementing value

Comment: What is your representation of "empty field"? 0? -1?

Comment: 0 represents empty fields in my 9x9 2 dimensional array int[,] sudokuBoard();

Comment: It begins with 1 and checks if 1 is valid in that position. If it is valid, it continues to the next empty field (0) and starts again with the number 1. If it's not valid at that position, the value should increment by one using the recursion. Onto the next free field: It tries 1, than 2, 3 ... and if no value is valid, the method should go back by one step and change the value of the previous free field. I hope I explained my problem in an understandable way.

Comment: If you watch the link that @ughStackExchange posted, it should answer your question. Basically, just reset `board[nextField.Value.X, nextField.Value.Y] = 0`, and go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snipping out the relevant part:

```
for (int value = 1; value < 10; value++)
{
    board[nextField.Value.X, nextField.Value.Y] = value;
    if(SolveSudoku(board)) return true;
    // ^^ Stop if solved,
    // iteration will increase value if not.
}
// reset and return false if no value for this field leads to a solution.
board[nextField.Value.X, nextField.Value.Y] = 0;
return false;
```